# Is it possible to pin ALL panel sections?

Tags: interface, customization

Since moving from 2.79 to 2.9, one thing that bothers me about the new UI is that it takes more steps to find what I'm looking for in the Properties Panel (N Panel).

Each "section" (if that's what you call them) is contextual by default, unless you pin it. And that context varies based on which Tab is selected on the right of the panel.

[image]

I'm finding myself spending a lot of time combing through searching for sections I used to simply scroll down and expand as needed. In an attempt to improve this situation I've started pinning each section as I encounter it, but some are only visible under specific circumstances, so getting each to appear, pinning it, and then saving my Startup File is getting a bit tedious. Furthermore, this needs to be done not only in the Properties Panel, but the "N Panels" of the other editors as well, such as the Shader Editor, UV Editor, etc.

**Is there a way to do one of the following?**

- Pin ALL panel sections with a setting or Python script
- Set that part of the UI to a "legacy" mode so it behaves like 2.79
- Solve this by some other means I haven't thought of (open to suggestions)

Thanks.

Comment: I've often hit the same issue and found no good solution so far. Pinning multiple panels across multiple tabs across multiple workspaces is indeed tedious. Editor synching couldn't come soon enough. I generally only pin one or two however, if you need various fixed panels pinned perhaps it is less of a hassle to just code your own custom tab in Python instead. Script it with all the frequent panels you require by default, should be worth the investment.